# Jquery carousel sliding issue in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, carousel

i used a jquery carousel in my site, it works fine in opera, safari, firefox, but not in chrome, when i click on next or previous button, it slides all li in one time, kindly help me.

regards

Warsi

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more specific info about your carousel plugin.

If it is not working fine, you can try other plugins like [jCarousel](https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel)